# iTextSharp - Sending in-memory pdf in an email attachment

Tags: c#, email, pdf, itext

I've asked a couple of questions here but am still having issues. I'd appreciate if you could tell me what I am doing wrong in my code. I run the code above from a ASP.Net page and get "Cannot Access a Closed Stream".

```
var doc = new Document();

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));

doc.Close(); //if I remove this line the email attachment is sent but with 0 bytes 

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("username@gmail.com", "username@gmail.com")
{
    Subject = "subject",
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = "body"
};

mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "test.pdf"));
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "my_password")
};

smtp.Send(mm); //the "Cannot Access a Closed Stream" error is thrown here
```

Thanks!!!

### EDIT:

Just to help somebody looking for the answer to this question, the code to send a pdf file attached to an email without having to physically create the file is below (thanks to Ichiban and Brianng):

```
var doc = new Document();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));

writer.CloseStream = false;
doc.Close();
memoryStream.Position = 0;

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("username@gmail.com", "username@gmail.com")
{
    Subject = "subject",
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = "body"
};

mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "filename.pdf"));
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")

};

smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: thanks for the line of the `position=0`. saved me!

Comment: Exactly what I need works perfectly thank you so much!
I was stuck on closing the document but not the stream: writer.CloseStream = false; cleared it up for me.

Comment: @Semil when putting up a bounty on an old question with an accepted answer, you really should indicate somehow what you miss in the answer.

Comment: writer.CloseStream = false; saved me as well, was missing that in a method that uses iTextSharp to turn HTML to PDF.  Before, passing the memorystream to my mail function failed due to the stream being closed.  Thanks.

Comment: This question may also help somebody.
[iText7 Create PDF in memory instead of physical file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540741/itext7-create-pdf-in-memory-instead-of-physical-file/64671854#64671854)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

// Build pdf code...

writer.CloseStream = false;
doc.Close();

// Build email

memoryStream.Position = 0;
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "test.pdf"));
```

If my memory serves me correctly, this solved a similar problem in a previous project.

See http://forums.asp.net/t/1093198.aspx

Comment: The set_CloseStream method is only available in the Java version. This is iTextSharp (.NET)

Comment: Sorry, again I haven't used iTextSharp (.NET) in a while, though the version I used definitely had set_CloseStream.

Comment: Changed to writer.CloseStream, and included related link.

Comment: Brianng, I really appreciate your help. I realize you and Ichiban kind of held my hand through it. Thanks!

Comment: If we keep the writer alive, when are we suppose to `writer.Flush()` then?

Comment: `writer.ClosStream = false; doc.Close();` solved the problem, thank you

Comment: What does "PdfWriter.CloseStream" do? We have old Code, where somebody who is on holiday for the next weeks changed something which made all PDF creation failing. If I set CloseStream to false, everything works like before but I really want to understand why.

Comment: @the-incredible-jan
PdfWriter.CloseStream tells itext if it may also close the PdfWriter stream when the doc.Close() method is called.

[another example to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540741/itext7-create-pdf-in-memory-instead-of-physical-file/64671854#64671854)

Answer (score 18):

I tried the code posted by [brianng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196059/itextsharp-sending-in-memory-pdf-in-an-email-attachment/1196125#1196125) and it worked. Just change the top of the code to this:

```
var doc = new Document();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream); //capture the object
doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));
writer.CloseStream = false; //set the closestream property
doc.close(); //close the document without closing the underlying stream
memoryStream.Position = 0;

/* remainder of your code stays the same*/
```

Comment: Hi Ichiban,
It compiles and it actually sends the email with the attachment, but the attached pdf document come across with 0kb. Did you actually open the pdf an email sent?

Comment: @Gustavo, the file opens correctly in Acrobat viewer. It is about 900 Bytes. Make sure you keep the line: memoryStream.Position=0; right after doc.Close(). I forgot to mention that. (see update above)

Comment: YES! Thank you so much guys. It finally worked. Since Ichiban's answer was based on brianng's, I think it's fair to mark brianng's answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Probably calling doc.Close() Disposes the underlying stream. Try removing doc.Close() and instead of that line set memoryStream.Position = 0;

Alternatively you can use a temp file:

```
var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

try 
{           
    var doc = new Document();

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, File.OpenWrite(tempFilePath));
    doc.Open();
    doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
    doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));

    doc.Close();

    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("username@gmail.com", "username@gmail.com")
    {
        Subject = "subject",
        IsBodyHtml = true,
        Body = "body"
    };

    mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(tempFilePath, "test.pdf"));
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "my_password")
    };

    smtp.Send(mm);
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(tempFilePath);
}
```

Comment: huseyint, I did what you suggested and the pdf file is sent, but it is only 15 bytes long. When I try opening it, it is corrupted.
I feel I am almost there with your suggestion. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Then try memoryStream.Flush(); before setting the Position

Comment: Same thing. The file is sent almost empty and corrupted. :(

Comment: Did you give "Creating a temp file" a try?

Comment: I am working on it right now and let you know shortly. Thanks!

Comment: Huseyint, thanks for your answer. I am pretty sure it would work but Brianng's answer is simpler as it doesn't require dealing with the server's file system. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Yes, definitely brianng's answer is the right way to achieve this. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 3):

Can you **flush** the document or memory stream and then close it after you attach it?

Comment: Hi James. I did this and the result did not change - I still get the "Cannot Access a Closed Stream" error. :( Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I used this post to solve it.In the code written by brianng

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

// Build pdf code...

writer.CloseStream = false;
doc.Close();

// Build email

memoryStream.Position = 0;
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "test.pdf"));
```

I think instead of writing

```
writer.CloseStream = false and memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Just create a new Stream

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(memoryStream);
```

and then call

```
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "test.pdf"));
```

Both work but I think it is better to create the new stream

Comment: Why is it better to create a new stream?

Comment: It's not. It's a waste of memory and CPU time because the bytes have to be copied from one to the other.

Comment: Dont remember why I said it is better. I think I might meant it is clearer. Sorry just saw this. Been a long time :)