# How to send generated pdf file as attachment in email from C#?

Tags: c#, email

i have code that generates a pdf file and i want to send it as an attachment to an email .

I have this code:

```
        FileContentResult fileContentResult = File(fileName, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
```

and i have this code to email an attachment

```
        Attachment a = new Attachment();
        sender.SendMail("a@a.com", "a@a.com", "subject", "Body", a);
```

how do i convert a **FileContentResult** into a **Attachment** object?

Comment: You probably want to use stuff the FileContents property of your FileContentResult instance into a memorystream and send.  The memorystream bit is shown here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196059/itextsharp-sending-in-memory-pdf-in-an-email-attachment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried using this: [Attachment Constructor (Stream, ContentType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab7hb4y5.aspx)?

Something like

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContentResult.FileContents); 
// Create an in-memory System.IO.Stream

ContentType ct = new ContentType(fileContentResult.ContentType);

Attachment a = new Attachment(ms, ct);
```

Comment: @Moron - this code doesn't compile.  i have renamed that variable above.  this line is not recognized:  ContentType ct = stream.ContentType;

Comment: @ooo: You need `using System.IO`, do you have that? Also edited code as stream.ContentType was apparently string.

Comment: @Moron - this line is not recognized: ContentType ct = stream.ContentType;

Answer (score 1):

I am just 7 years late, but here is your answer:

```
Attachment a = new Attachment(fileName, "application/pdf");
sender.SendMail("a@a.com", "a@a.com", "subject", "Body", a);
```