# How to programatically publish ebooks to Kindle, Sony Reader etc.?

Tags: c#, vb.net, kindle

I would like to use .NET platform to do this.  I should be able to convert word documents, pdf files, assign a password and publish it to kindle, sony reader.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check Calibre ( http://calibre-ebook.com/ ), it has a command line interface and several conversion options to convert things to `.mobi`, which can then be sent to Kindle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about word documents.  I'd convert word documents to PDF's. There are libraries available to convert word docs to PDFs. The Kindle and Sony Reader both support PDF's. As for programatically publishing them to the reader. I have never tried.

Answer (score 0):

Both the kindle and sony reader can read pdf's so you can use this directly. There are also several libraries for .Net which can programatically create pdf files.

Not sure how you want to publish. As I have only operated a kindle you can either save to it over USB or email it to username@kindle.com in order to transfer a file. I don't think you can push it yourself like Amazon does.

An alternative to pdf are the mobi file format. More information at http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI#Format

Comment: Thanks Mikael!  Is there any security enabled around username@kindle.com? What if I send a pdf file to username@kindle.com, even though it is not my account?

Comment: You have to authorize the senders address, to prevent spam.

Comment: But, how do you that, say if I am using asp.net to send a ebook to username@kindle.com?  Any documentation?  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196059/itextsharp-sending-in-memory-pdf-in-an-email-attachment