# Silverlight to Web Service not Working?

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, email, itext

I have a simple Silverlight web app form I created to test a web service I have set up for a bigger project. This form is basically textboxes that take First Name, Last Name, and Middle Name, and on button click, the code gets passed on to the web service on the server, which prints them in a pdf form, saves it to disk, then emails it. 
I’ve written all the code, I don’t get any errors, but it’s not working. No file gets saved and no email gets sent.
Here’s the code from the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ServiceModel;
using ExampleSilverlightApp.ServiceReference1;

namespace ExampleSilverlightApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.newpdfRequestBody proxy = new ServiceReference1.newpdfRequestBody();
        proxy._1_FirstName = textBox1.Text;
        proxy._1_lastName = textBox2.Text;
        proxy._1_middlename = textBox3.Text;

    }
}
```

}

And here’s the code from my web service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ExampleSilverlightApp.Web
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public void newpdf(string _1_FirstName, string _1_lastName, string _1_middlename)
        {

            string filename = @"C:\Temp\" + _1_FirstName + _1_lastName + ".pdf";
            iTextSharp.text.Document d = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 72, 72, 172, 72);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

            d.Open();
            d.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format("First Name:", _1_FirstName)));
            d.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format("Last Name:", _1_lastName)));
            d.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format("Middle Name:", _1_middlename)));
            d.Close();
            try
            {
                MailAddress SendFrom = new MailAddress("t@hotmail.com");
                MailAddress SendTo = new MailAddress("tg@gmail.com");

                MailMessage MyMessage = new MailMessage(SendFrom, SendTo);
                MyMessage.Subject = "new test";
                MyMessage.Body = "heres a new test!";

                Attachment attachfile = new Attachment(filename);
                MyMessage.Attachments.Add(attachfile);

                SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
                emailClient.Send(MyMessage);
            }

            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Lost!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I can’t tell what is wrong with what I have set up.

Comment: I don't see who calls newpdf service method, are you sure your posted code is complete?

Comment: have you tried renaming your `_1_FirstName` to simple recommended convention `firstName`?

Comment: Is your xap file hosted on the same domain as the server? Silverlight do not allow cross domain access without a clientaccesspolicy.xml on the server. See here if thats the case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Start that "try/catch" block from the beginning of the method. probably you have the write permission error on the server.
- Try another method. you can create an in memory pdf file and then send it as an email. in this case your program doesn't need special permissions on the server. more info:[[^]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196059/itextsharp-sending-in-memory-pdf-in-an-email-attachment)