# C# send a file in email to the Kindle device

Tags: c#, email

I'm trying to send a PDF file for a Kindle device.

If I send that file using my GMAIL account (sending via web browser) the file is sent properly (I can see that file under the Amazon > Manage Your Kindle section)

My SmtpClient configuration code is fine - any emails under my project are being sent properly.

Only sending a file as an email attachment is not working, I don't see that file in the Amazon > Manage Your Kindle section. The code below doesn't throw any exceptions or errors, the message is sent.

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = "SMTP_SERVER",
            Port = "SMTP_PORT",
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass")
        };

var msg = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("my_email", "my_name"),
                          new MailAddress("some_name@kindle.com"))
            {
                Subject = "Your Kindle file",
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };

            Attachment data = new Attachment(PDF_file_path,
                                             MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
            msg.Attachments.Add(data);

            smtp.Send(msg);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: you should wrap the new MailMessage in a using statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out - after I have to add my email address to the trusted emails list in the Amazon account (Personal Document Settings > Approved Personal Document E-mail List)

Then the mail had been delivered. Thanks guys !

Comment: You should really accept Léon’s answer instead of writing your own as that’s exactly what he described…

Answer (score 1):

When you send it to another email, the attached file is present?

Did you debug the program just before the send command?

Is this ok when you're sending it from your email address?

Is there email firewall rules in the "Your Kindle approved e-mail list" menu, in the "Manage Your Kindle" settings?

I know that there is no restriction in Kindle t&c regarding file attachments.
Amazon only asks for the file to be in a recognized ebook format.

[iTextSharp - Sending in-memory pdf in an email attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196059/itextsharp-sending-in-memory-pdf-in-an-email-attachment)

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10238481/attachment-file-is-missing.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new user, so I cannot comment yet. Sometime, my answers are converted to comment, sometime no.

Comment: Yes, I have sent that email to myself (gmail) and I see that attached file

Comment: As Tony says, if you wrap it in a using statement, it would allow long process like adding the attachment to be executed without problem.

Comment: I have wrap the MailMessage in the using statement, without success

Comment: So, it was on the Amazon website, and not in your kindle approved e-mail list?