# Saving a generated file to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating a PDF with the handy iText for C#. Now, I basically just need to generate this PDF and e-mail it. At the moment I can generate the file in PDF, but I don't want to hardcode a path to save the file. Example, I am saving the file like this:

```
        string file = "C:\\Receipts\" + ConfirmationNumber + ".pdf";
```

Now, hardcoding a path like that is completely against best practices. How can I save the file properly, following best practice? Maybe to a folder inside the project itself? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you *have* to write the file to disk?  It's easy enough to send an iText created pdf directly to email from this **[SO answer from Brianng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196059/itextsharp-sending-in-memory-pdf-in-an-email-attachment)**

```
var doc = new Document();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));

writer.CloseStream = false;
doc.Close();
memoryStream.Position = 0;

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("username@gmail.com", "username@gmail.com")
{
    Subject = "subject",
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = "body"
};

mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "filename.pdf"));
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
};

smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: This worked much better. No need to save to the folder and keep giving it maintenance by deleting files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I am also in same situation. I have a crystal report. i want to generate pdf from crystal report and send mail. As now its generating pdf and saving in local machine. i want to save in a server folder. Is there any way to do this??  I am using the following code to generate the pdf.

                _RPT.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Quotation Report 00" );_

Comment: You would have to contact the authors of iText to see if they have any interface for Crystal Reports.  My answer here was over 3 years ago and was actually a reference to another SO user.

Answer (score 1):

If you have HttpContext, you can use [PhysicalApplicationPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string filePath = string.Format("{0}\\App_Data\\ExportImport\\{1}", 
   HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, fileName);
```

If you do not have HttpContext, you can use [AppDomainAppPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string filePath = string.Format("{0}App_Data\\ExportImport\\{1}",
   HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, fileName);
```

Comment: Make sure the folder exists in your web application before saving the file.